# How to fix d3.js chart scaling

Tags: d3.js, line, zooming

I would like to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172#sp500.csv).

But when I zoom it, the line is out of the area.

line definition:

```
var valueline_1 = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x_1(parseDate(d.date)); })
  .y(function (d) { return y_1(d.count); });

var valueline2_1 = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x2_1(parseDate(d.date)); })
  .y(function (d) { return y2_1(d.count); });
```

and then this code:

```
focus_1.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline_1(i));

context_1.append("path")
  .data([data])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", valueline2_1);
```

[image]
Can you help how to fix it?

thx.

**EDIT:**
This code for zoom:

```
var zoom_0 = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width_0, height_0]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width_0, height_0]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed_0);

function zoomed_0() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush"
    ) return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x_0.domain(t.rescaleX(x2_0).domain());
    focus_0.select(".area").attr("d", area_0);
    focus_0.select(".line").attr("d", valueline_0);
    focus_0.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis_0);
    context_0.select(".brush").call(brush_0.move, x_0.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}
```

I have multiple charts on page. From 1 to 5 - for this purpose I append  `_{number}`

Comment: Show the code for "zoom" event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did not apply [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) style. If you switch off this style in blocks that you mentioned it will look like your screen, (see demo gif below):

[image]

Check that you append `defs` element and `clipPath` element as child for `defs`:

```
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
```

Also, check that you have this style:

```
.line { // <== this class name should be on your line/area
  clip-path: url(#clip); // <== !!!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this helps me for first chart only. I have on my page 5 charts, each in separated tabs. For others problem persist. clip-pats is enabled.  Any idea?

Comment: @TomášČičman Try to set a unique id for every chart. For, example, for the first chart, it should be `clip1`, for the second - `clip2`... And change your styles in accordance with this.

Comment: I have same idea - but too late :D Thank you for help

Comment: Do you know how to add tooltips for each peak?

Comment: There are some ways to achieve it. Check this - http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369 or this - https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/cfb7dcd7951826b9eacd54f0647f48d3 examples.